# Trouble with selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm pretty new to using CSS, and have been working on some WordPress template projects. I feel like this is a very simple problem that I've run in to, but I can't find documentation or previous questions that answer it for me, my apologies if they are out there!

What I'm trying to do is format a `<ul>` and links within that list in a specific way. That `<ul>` comes from the "Pages" widget in WordPress, and lives in

```
<aside id="pages-2" class="widget widget_pages">
```

which is in

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
```

In my style sheet, I've added these lines:

```
.widget-area ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.widget-area a {
    color: black;
}
.widget-area a:visited {
    color: red;
}
.widget-area a:hover,
.widget-area a:focus,
.widget-area a:active {
    color: midnightblue;
}
```

However, the elements are still styled in the way the `ul` and `a` elements are styled without the specificity of the `.widget-area`. I have had success with these lines though:

```
.widget-area {
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 247px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The site is here: http://ccarrollmusic.com/

Answer (score 0):

With CSS there are a few reasons this could be happening,

1. Your changes might be getting overwrote by a class or id style on the element having the `!important` attribute.
2. Your file could be loading before the Wordpress CSS file that is setting those styles in the first place
3. What I guess is most likely is there is a more specific rule which is taking over.

It's best to do something like:

```
#secondary .widget-area ul li a:hover,
#secondary .widget-area ul li a:focus,
#secondary .widget-area ul li a:active {
    color: midnightblue;
}
```

Comment: I mentioned this in a comment on dippas' answer, but I don't use the `!important` attribute anywhere, and as far as I know there is only the one CSS file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can successfully target the ul in the widget in question by using the id of the aside that is its' immediate parent:

```
aside#pages-2 ul li a {
    color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dan! I found a different way around in an answer that I just posted, where I also raised another question.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been able to solve this by simply using `.widget-area ul`, however I moved it up in the style sheet so that it comes directly after I stle `.widget-area` and that seems to have done the trick. Earlier, there was mention of `.page_item` between `.widget-area` and `.widget-area ul`. Is there importance as to the order of style declarations and specificity? Because I didn't think that would be important I didn't include it in the original question, sorry about that!